# How to call a resource from one yaml template to another yaml template using cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I need some guidance on cloudformation templates.

I have a stack called `test1.yaml`, there i created an IAM role called **S3Role**.

Now I have another stack called `test2.yaml`, there i created a managed policy to attach to existing iam role.

Now i want to call `test1.yml` file **S3Role** in `test2.yml` file of managed policy.

Can anyone help me with the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone help me with the script.

Obviously due to lack of details in your question, its not possible to provide any script. But I can provide general **psudo-code**.

**test1.yaml**

You will have to [export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) the S3Role Arn or Name

```
Resources:

  S3Role:
    Type: IAM::ROLE
    <rest of role definition>

Outputs:

  RoleArn:
     Value: !GetAtt  S3Role.Arn
     Exports:
        Name: RoleArn
```

**test2.yml**
You will have to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) the role exported Arn (or name) from `test1.yaml`:

```
Resources:
  
  SomeResouce:
     Properties:
       Role: !ImportValue RoleArn
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need export the role from stack 1 and then import it in stack 2

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

Answer (score 0):

Providing the complete script for cross-referencing an AWS resource in CloudFormation template.

**test1.yaml** has an IAM role (logical ID: IAMRole) which we export through the *Outputs* block. Also notice that the indentation of *Outputs* block is same as that of *Resources* block.

The *Outputs* block serves many purposes. From the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html#:%7E:text=AWS%20glossary-,Outputs,-RSS)

> The optional Outputs section declares output values that you can
> import into other stacks (to create cross-stack references), return in
> response (to describe stack calls), or view on the AWS CloudFormation
> console.

**test1.yaml**

```
Resources:
  IAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Sid: TrustPolicy
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:    
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
      Path: / 
      RoleName: IAMRole

Outputs:
  ExportIAMRole:
    Description: Export the IAMRole to use in test2.yaml
    Value: !Ref IAMRole
    Export: 
      Name: IAMRole
```

In **test2.yaml** we import the value by referencing the name we have given under *Export* in *Outputs* block.

**test2.yaml**

```
Resources:
  IAMPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: IAMPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - kms:ListAliases
              - kms:Encrypt
              - kms:Decrypt
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - !ImportValue IAMRole
```